# sparkR with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, sparkr

I want to read a dataframe that comes from a cassandra keyspace and column_family. When running sparkR, I am calling the respective spark-cassandra-connector package, and setting the conf to my local spark cassandra host. I do not get any error when running the below.

```
$ ./bin/sparkR --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:1.5.0-M2 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1
```

```
sc <- sparkR.init(master="local")
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
people <-read.df(sqlContext,
    source = "org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra",
    keyspace = "keyspace_name", table = "table_name")
```

I get the following error,

```
Error in writeJobj(con, object) : invalid jobj 1
```

Do I have to pass conf into the `sparkContext` assignment (sc), and how in sparkR?

Below is my spark and cassandra versions,

Spark: 1.5.1
Cassandra: 2.1.6
Cassandra Connector updated to use 1.5.0-M2 per zero323 advice

Here is a gist to my stack trace.

https://gist.github.com/bhajer3/419561edcb0dc5db2f71

**Edit**:

I am able to create data frames from tables which do not include any Cassandra collection datatypes, 
such as Map, Set and List.  But, many of the schemas that I need data from, do include these collection data types.

Thus, sparkR does not have support for cassandra collection data types, when reading a dataframe that comes from a Cassandra keyspace and column_family. See here for my detailed report/testing procedures.

https://gist.github.com/bhajer3/c3effa92de8e3cfc4fee

Comment: A couple of notes: 1) Please don't post updates or additional questions as answers. 2) If you solved the problem and encountered another one please don't edit the question to change the scope but resolve the existing one and ask a new one. Otherwise you render existing answers invalid and reduce value of the question for the other users. 3) If you a have code that can be used to reproduce the problem please post it as the part of the question itself. External sources make sense only if it is a live example (sqlfiddle, jsbin)

Comment: Will do, sorry about that @zero323, thanks for the help.

Comment: Sure, I've provided an explanation why collecting complex types doesn't work on 1.5. It is simply not supported.

Comment: The fix will be in spark 1.6. Thanks @zero323

Answer (score 1):

**The initial problem**:

Generally speaking you have to match Spark, `spark-cassandra-connector` and Cassandra versions. Connector version should match major Spark version  (connector 1.5 for Spark 1.5, connector 1.4 for Spark 1.4 and so on).

Compatibility with Cassandra version is a little bit more tricky but you can find a full list of compatible versions in [connector README.md](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility).

**Edit**:

SparkR < 1.6 doesn't support collecting complex data types including arrays or maps. It has been solved by [SPARK-10049](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10049). If you build Spark form master it works as expected. There is no `cassandra-connector` for 1.6 but 1.5-M2 seems to works just fine, at least with DataFrame API.

**Note**:

It looks like connector 1.5-M2 incorrectly reports `Date` keys as `Timestamps` so please beware if you use these in your database.